# creating a folder inside existing folder in google drive using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am creating an application using `asp.net mvc` and `javascript` in which I want to create folders inside my existing google drive folder.

below is my code which I got from stackoverflow

```
function createFolder() {
    var body = {
        'title': document.getElementById('txtFolderName').value,
        'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    };

    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.insert({
        'resource': body
    });

    request.execute(function (resp) {
        console.log('Folder ID: ' + resp.id);
    });
}
```

I am getting the below error

> index.html:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'files')

on the following line

> var request = gapi.client.drive.files.insert({

here `gapi.client.drive` is appearing to be undefined

below is my code to authenticate and load google api client

```
function authenticate(callback) {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({ scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" })
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Sign-in successful");
            callback == undefined ? '' : callback();
        },
            function (err) {
                console.error("Error signing in", err);
            });
}
function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("APIKEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1")
        .then(function () {
            console.log("GAPI client loaded for API");
        },
            function (err) {
                console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err);
            });
}
```

what is the problem here?

and what I need to do if I want to create a folder inside another folder?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that in your script, `https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1` of `gapi.client.load("https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1")` is used for Google Docs API v1. I think that the reason for your error message of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')` is due to this.

In your goal, it seems that you want to create a folder into a specific folder. In this case, please use Drive API. But, when I saw your current script for creating the folder, Drive API v2 is used. So, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
return gapi.client.load("https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1")
```

#### To:

```
return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest")
```

- By this modification, I thought that your `createFolder()` works. But in your current `createFolder()`, the folder is created to the root folder. When you want to create the folder into a specific folder, please modify the request body as follows.

  ```
    var body = {
      'title': document.getElementById('txtFolderName').value,
      'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
      'parents': [{'id': '###folderId###'}]
    };
  ```

#### Note:

- As additional information, if you want to use Drive API v3, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      return gapi.client.load("https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1")
    ```
  - To

    ```
      return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest")
    ```
  - And, please modify `createFolder()` as follows.

    ```
      var body = {
        'name': document.getElementById('txtFolderName').value,
        'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
        'parents': ['###folderId###']
      };

      var request = gapi.client.drive.files.create({ 'resource': body });
    ```

#### References:

- [Files: insert of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [Files: create of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)